# Unity3D 8th Wall XR, can't compile demo project on android

Tags: unity-game-engine, 8thwall-xr

I have a problem compiling the 8th wall xr unity demo project on android.
(Source: https://console.8thwall.com/quick-start)
I tried different JDKs, Android Toolsets, Changed the JAVA_HOME environment path, nothing seems to work.

That's the error log I keep getting:

> CommandInvokationFailure: Gradle build failed.  C:\Program
>   Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_144\bin\java.exe -classpath "C:\Program
>   Files\Unity2017_3\Editor\Data\PlaybackEngines\AndroidPlayer\Tools\gradle\lib\gradle-launcher-4.0.1.jar"
>   org.gradle.launcher.GradleMain "-Dorg.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx2048m"
>   "assembleDebug"
>
> stderr[
>   C:\Users\kehrc\Desktop\XRTest\8thWallXRDemo\Temp\gradleOut\build\generated\source\r\debug\com\private\xrTest\R.java:8:
>   error:  expected package com.private.xrTest;
>               ^ C:\Users\kehrc\Desktop\XRTest\8thWallXRDemo\Temp\gradleOut\build\generated\source\r\debug\com\private\xrTest\R.java:8:
>   error: class, interface, or enum expected package com.private.xrTest;
>                      ^ C:\Users\kehrc\Desktop\XRTest\8thWallXRDemo\Temp\gradleOut\build\generated\source\r\debug\com\private\xrTest\R.java:8:
>   error: class, interface, or enum expected package com.private.xrTest;
>                       ^ C:\Users\kehrc\Desktop\XRTest\8thWallXRDemo\Temp\gradleOut\build\generated\source\buildConfig\debug\com\private\xrTest\BuildConfig.java:4:
>   error:  expected package com.private.xrTest;
>               ^ C:\Users\kehrc\Desktop\XRTest\8thWallXRDemo\Temp\gradleOut\build\generated\source\buildConfig\debug\com\private\xrTest\BuildConfig.java:4:
>   error: class, interface, or enum expected package com.private.xrTest;
>                      ^ C:\Users\kehrc\Desktop\XRTest\8thWallXRDemo\Temp\gradleOut\build\generated\source\buildConfig\debug\com\private\xrTest\BuildConfig.java:4:
>   error: class, interface, or enum expected package com.private.xrTest;
>                       ^ 6 errors
>
> FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
>
> - What went wrong: Execution failed for task ':compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.
>
>   > Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.
> - Try: Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
>
> BUILD FAILED in 2s ] stdout[ Observed package id
>   'add-ons;addon-unknown-unknown-23' in inconsistent location
>   'C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\Android\android-sdk\add-ons\addon-google_apis-google-23'
>   (Expected 'C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\Android\android-sdk\add-ons\addon-unknown-unknown-23') Observed
>   package id 'build-tools;26.0.0-rc2' in inconsistent location
>   'C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\Android\android-sdk\build-tools\26.0.0-preview' (Expected
>   'C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\build-tools\26.0.0-rc2')
>   The setTestClassesDir(File) method has been deprecated and is
>   scheduled to be removed in Gradle 5.0. Please use the
>   setTestClassesDirs(FileCollection) method instead. The
>   getTestClassesDir() method has been deprecated and is scheduled to be
>   removed in Gradle 5.0. Please use the getTestClassesDirs() method
>   instead. The ConfigurableReport.setDestination(Object) method has been
>   deprecated and is scheduled to be removed in Gradle 5.0. Please use
>   the method ConfigurableReport.setDestination(File) instead. :preBuild
>   UP-TO-DATE :preDebugBuild UP-TO-DATE :checkDebugManifest
>   :preReleaseBuild UP-TO-DATE :prepareXRPluginLibrary
>   :prepareDebugDependencies :compileDebugAidl UP-TO-DATE
>   :compileDebugRenderscript UP-TO-DATE :generateDebugBuildConfig
>   UP-TO-DATE :generateDebugResValues UP-TO-DATE :generateDebugResources
>   UP-TO-DATE :mergeDebugResources UP-TO-DATE :processDebugManifest
>   :processDebugResources :generateDebugSources
>   :incrementalDebugJavaCompilationSafeguard UP-TO-DATE
>   :javaPreCompileDebug :compileDebugJavaWithJavac FAILED 13 actionable
>   tasks: 7 executed, 6 up-to-date ] exit code: 1
>   UnityEditor.Android.Command.WaitForProgramToRun
>   (UnityEditor.Utils.Program p,
>   UnityEditor.Android.WaitingForProcessToExit waitingForProcessToExit,
>   System.String errorMsg) UnityEditor.Android.Command.Run
>   (System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo psi,
>   UnityEditor.Android.WaitingForProcessToExit waitingForProcessToExit,
>   System.String errorMsg) UnityEditor.Android.AndroidJavaTools.RunJava
>   (System.String args, System.String workingdir, System.Action`1
>   progress, System.String error) UnityEditor.Android.GradleWrapper.Run
>   (System.String workingdir, System.String task, System.Action`1
>   progress) Rethrow as GradleInvokationException: Gradle build failed
>   UnityEditor.Android.GradleWrapper.Run (System.String workingdir,
>   System.String task, System.Action`1 progress)
>   UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessor.Tasks.BuildGradleProject.Execute
>   (UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessor.PostProcessorContext context)
>   UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessor.PostProcessRunner.RunAllTasks
>   (UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessor.PostProcessorContext context)
>   UnityEngine.GUIUtility:ProcessEvent(Int32, IntPtr)

Windows Version: 
Windows 10 64-Bit Professional

Unity Version: 
2017.3.1f1

I tried the "internal" build as well, not working either.

Does anyone have an idea where the problem may be coming from, or what else i could try ?

Best wishes,
Chris

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your package name for the project is "com.private.xrTest". `private` is a keyword in Java, so you get the compiler error stating that an identifier is expected after `private`.

Changing your package name should resolve the compiler error.

Comment: I tested it and it is compiling.

Comment: I tested it and it is compiling. Thank you so much ! Amazing support by 8th wall :):)